# Spring Boot and JpaRepository sort by distance with latitude and longitude params

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa-2.0, geospatial

I have a problem creating a query using the JpaRepository interface. I use the Pageable mechanism. How can I add sort by distance? Geographic parameters available at Event Place. (Latitude, longitude). I would like to add also the ability to limit distance by range. E.g:
"Where distance <: range".
I would like the distance to be returned in the "distance" field, which is @Transient.

EventRepository

```
@Repository
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long> {

public static final String GET_PAGE_QUERY = "WHERE " +
        "(:searchTerm is null or e.title like '%:searchTerm%') AND " +
        "((:userListId) is null or e.user.id in (:userListId)) AND " +
        "((:sportTypeIdList) is null or e.sportType.id in (:sportTypeIdList)) " ;


@Query(value = "SELECT e FROM Event e " + GET_PAGE_QUERY,
        countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Event e " + GET_PAGE_QUERY)
    Page<Event> getPage(@Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm, @Param("userListId") List<Long> userListId, @Param("sportTypeIdList") List<Long> sportTypeIdList, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Event

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "event_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "event_seq", sequenceName = "event_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "TITLE", length = 50, nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 500, nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 500)
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    private SportType sportType;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    private EventPlace place;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private User user;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
    @Column(name = "CREATE_DATE", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @NotNull
    private Date createDate = new Date();

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
    @Column(name = "START_DATE", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @NotNull
    private Date startDate;

    @Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EventStatus status = EventStatus.ACTIVE;

    @Transient
    private double distance;
}
```

EventPlace

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class EventPlace {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "event_place_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "event_place_seq", sequenceName = "event_place_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 50, nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "CITY", length = 50, nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "STREET", length = 50, nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "ZIP_CODE", length = 50, nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String zipCode;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 500, nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 500)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "LATITUDE", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Double latitude;

    @Column(name = "LONGITUDE", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Double longitude;

}
```

Comment: On DB level, you could use the [`earthdistance` contrib module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/earthdistance.html), or the [PostGIS extension](http://postgis.net) to help you calculate geospacial distances. Do you use any of them? -- Spring data also has some support for geospatial queries (i.e. through the `GeoResult` & `GeoResults` repository return types), but I'm not sure if those are supported for PostgreSQL too (I only found examples for MongoDB).